# How to hide search on single select chosen jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, jquery-chosen

I've read in chosen jquery at http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ . Ok i want to "Hide Search on Single Select" as same example in that (example in guthub/chosen above), such as `FLAG=false` hide them. How can i do it?

```js
var data = [{
    "BU_ID": "B01",
        "BU_NAME": "Agro Feed",
        "BU_DES": "Agro Feed",
        "EDIT_DATE": "2015-05-05T00:00:00",
        "EDIT_BY": "",
        "FLAG": true
}, {
    "BU_ID": "B02",
        "BU_NAME": "Agro Farm",
        "BU_DES": "Agro Farm",
        "EDIT_DATE": "2015-05-05T00:00:00",
        "EDIT_BY": "",
        "FLAG": false
},{
    "BU_ID": "B03",
        "BU_NAME": "Agro Food",
        "BU_DES": "Agro Food",
        "EDIT_DATE": "2015-05-05T00:00:00",
        "EDIT_BY": "",
        "FLAG": true
}
           ];

$("#cb_info").empty();
$.each(data, function (idx, obj) {
    $("#cb_info").append('<option value="' + obj.BU_ID + '">' + obj.BU_NAME + '</option>');
}); 
$("#cb_info").chosen({ width: "auto" });
$("#cb_info").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.0/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.0/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<select id="cb_info"></select>
```

Thank guys.

Comment: Quite Unclear.. can you elaborate on _hide search on single select_ with an example?

Comment: do you want to hide options which have `Flag:false`?

Comment: Dear @MKA , exactly as you say .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RA8ej/166/

Comment: Dear @MKA ,if as link of you , i know, but in here, I want to show all (3 option : 2 show and 1 hide ) as same example in github (a example "Hide Search on Single Select").thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not that clear . But if what you want is to disable items with FLAG:false then just specify the disabled property for those options.

```js
var data = [{
    "BU_ID": "B01",
        "BU_NAME": "Agro Feed",
        "BU_DES": "Agro Feed",
        "EDIT_DATE": "2015-05-05T00:00:00",
        "EDIT_BY": "",
        "FLAG": true
}, {
    "BU_ID": "B02",
        "BU_NAME": "Agro Farm",
        "BU_DES": "Agro Farm",
        "EDIT_DATE": "2015-05-05T00:00:00",
        "EDIT_BY": "",
        "FLAG": false
},{
    "BU_ID": "B03",
        "BU_NAME": "Agro Food",
        "BU_DES": "Agro Food",
        "EDIT_DATE": "2015-05-05T00:00:00",
        "EDIT_BY": "",
        "FLAG": true
}
           ];

$("#cb_info").empty();
$.each(data, function (idx, obj) {
var status = (!obj.FLAG)?'disabled':'';
    $("#cb_info").append('<option '+status+' value="' + obj.BU_ID + '">' + obj.BU_NAME + '</option>');
}); 
$("#cb_info").chosen({ width: "auto" });
$("#cb_info").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.0/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.0/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<select id="cb_info"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [{
    "BU_ID": "B01",
        "BU_NAME": "Agro Feed",
        "BU_DES": "Agro Feed",
        "EDIT_DATE": "2015-05-05T00:00:00",
        "EDIT_BY": "",
        "FLAG": true
}, {
    "BU_ID": "B02",
        "BU_NAME": "Agro Farm",
        "BU_DES": "Agro Farm",
        "EDIT_DATE": "2015-05-05T00:00:00",
        "EDIT_BY": "",
        "FLAG": false
}, {
    "BU_ID": "B03",
        "BU_NAME": "Agro Food",
        "BU_DES": "Agro Food",
        "EDIT_DATE": "2015-05-05T00:00:00",
        "EDIT_BY": "",
        "FLAG": true
}];

$("#cb_info").empty();
$.each(data, function (idx, obj) {
    if (obj.FLAG === true) {
        $("#cb_info").append('<option value="' + obj.BU_ID + '">' + obj.BU_NAME + '</option>');
    }
});
```

Just add a condition `if (obj.FLAG === true) {`
only flag with true will be added on the list therefor you don't need to hide anything

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6okneLwt/)

**UPDATED**

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6okneLwt/1/)

Comment: Dear @Pekka,as your answer , I know but in here, i want to show all ( 3 option: 2 option enable and 1 option visible)

Comment: @BrianCrist `such as FLAG=false hide them` As i understand this one you want to hide if flag is false. Can you explain what you really wanted.

Comment: Dear @Pekka, thank for your answer. i founded an answer from jacky rudetsky

Comment: I still updated my answer incase someone needs a reference happy coding @BrianCrist. Although the question was a bit off i am happy someone was able to answer correctly

Comment: happy coding @BrianCrist